# XPath Predicate "is parent the current node?"

Tags: xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0

I have a node set and I'd like to use a predicate to select from it only those nodes which have a template's current node as their parent.

I'm using XSL 1.0 and msxsl.

In the following non-working code, the predicate [parent::current()] does not work as I want it to as current() is not a valid NodeTest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:variable name="set" select="//node[@attr1 = 'bbb']"/>

    <xsl:template name="TemplateA">
        <xsl:for-each select="$set[parent::current()]">
            <result-node>
                <xsl:value-of select="@value"/>
                <xsl:text>A</xsl:text>
            </result-node>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="TemplateB">
        <xsl:for-each select="$set[parent::current()]">
            <result-node>
                <xsl:value-of select="@value"/>
                <xsl:text>B</xsl:text>
            </result-node>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/body">
        <result>
        <xsl:for-each select="parentNode">
            <xsl:call-template name="TemplateA" />
            <xsl:call-template name="TemplateB" />
        </xsl:for-each>
        </result>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

Here is a sample XML to feed the above:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<body>
    <parentNode>
        <node attr1="aaa" value="1" />
        <node attr1="bbb" value="2" />
    </parentNode>

    <parentNode>
        <node attr1="aaa" value="3" />
        <node attr1="bbb" value="4" />
    </parentNode>
</body>
```

Here is the desired output:

```
<result>
    <result-node>2A</result-node>
    <result-node>2B</result-node>
    <result-node>4A</result-node>
    <result-node>4B</result-node>
</result>
```

The above example can also be found here: http://xsltransform.net/jyH9rMg

Comment: A complete, answerable question! But again, calling named templates might not be necessary - depending on the extent of your actual code. Also, notice that there is `version="2.0"` in your code, you should change it to `version="1.0"`.

Comment: Servus Mathias. Corrected as suggested. My actual code is very complicated, so I have presented a simplified example for SO. I used the same techniques in the example as in my real code to avoid inadvertently asking the wrong question. But that said, if you have a suggestion for a better way of doing the same thing I (and others) may be able to learn from it. If you feel inspired to do this, please add this to the xsltransform.net link. (And a big thank you for showing me xsltransform.net!)

Comment: Then, it's perfectly okay - if you've downsized your code considerably before posting it here that's exactly the right thing to do. And then I'm confident you had good reason to have named templates. And yes, the xsltransform site is pretty awesome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way to compare nodes for identity in XSLT 1.0 is to use `generate-id()`:

```
<xsl:for-each select="$set[generate-id(..) = generate-id(current())]">
```

`..` is a shorthand for `parent::node()` and refers to the parent of the context node (the node being tested by this execution of the predicate).

Comment: @CaptainNormal Regarding your suggested edit: `..` is as valid as `parent::*` - and actually, the shorthand way comes in handy sometimes. So, I would not want you to edit it out. You could ask Ian to edit his answer and include a short description of `..` though.

Comment: @CaptainNormal if you do get the chance to upgrade to XSLT 2.0 it becomes even shorter using the `is` operator - `$set[.. is current()]`